# Apache as intranet webserver with 'internet' content

Tags: apache, proxy, intranet

I have a working Apache 2 set-up for intranet purposes.
The Apache server only needs to serve pages to local, intranet clients.
However, in these pages I would like to serve *internet* content. For example content from external RSS feeds in a feedreader like this one:

http://dev.sencha.com/deploy/dev/examples/feed-viewer/view.html

The Apache server is located on a Windows Server 2003.
Normal clients in the intranet zone connect to the internet via a proxy server.
A browser on this server also is able to connect to the internet.

My question is how to change my set-up so that Apache can get content from outside the local network without the need to serve pages outside the local intranet.

Regards,
Fabio

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use Php curl to fetch external (*internet*) content.  http://php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php

Comment: I guess your answer means there is no general solution and I have to look for a 'page' specific solution?

Comment: I recently wrote a curl script, that is fairly general. It can handle most internet pages and content (with POST/GET parameters). Essentially it acts as a relay server (some 50-60 lines of code).  And no - I don't mean that there is no other general solution, but this is just something I did recently and *could* work for you as *one potential solution*.

Comment: Thanks. Will look into curl.
Succeeded in connecting by using this solution: http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php#58758 
Probably some curl code is more clear, as for the above solution I had to install a small proxy authentication server(Cntlm). 
I'll return and edit my question when I've determined the most sensible solution.